# Market Basket Analysis - single model for variable number of features?

Tags: r, machine-learning, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am using Apriori to build a recommender system to go along with my company's application. Before going down this road, I'd like to confirm with someone that has more experience that I am on the right track. Any help is appreciated.

Let me try to explain the issue. Depending on the context of the user within the application, the features that impact the recommendations can vary. For example, imagine a shopping scenario. If I shop at HEB, I usually have a predefined grocery list so the items on that list would be good recommendations if I just told the app I was going to HEB. When I go to Home Depot though, I tend to shop by department, so power tools and the associated parts are good recommendations if I tell the app I'm at Home Depot and I am doing shopping for power tools.

You see that the number of features varies in the two scenarios. In the first, my recommendations depend solely on the store while in the second, they depend on the store and the department in which I'm shopping.

I am looking to use a single Apriori model that can handle this type of situation. Would that be considered a best practice or is it better to have different models, one for when we just list the store and another for when we list the store and the department? Given that Apriori is an unsupervised algorithm, I think it can be done with one model, but wanted to double check since I don't have a ton of experience.

Comment: If you need help with model selection, you should be asking at [stats.se], not here. This does not seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of this.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you are talking about multi-level association rules. This is from the manual page of the `aggregate` function in `arules`:

> Support for Item Hierarchies
>
> Description:
>
> Often an item hierarchy is available for datasets used for
>   association rule mining. For example in a supermarket dataset
>   items like "bread" and "beagle" might belong to the item group
>   (category) "baked goods."

I guess the higher-level categories would be your departments and stores. This will be able to find associations between items, departments and stores.